# Apache2 ForensicLog timestamp

Tags: apache-2.4, forensics

I'm using apache2 with ForensicLog enabled by this directive below.

```
ForensicLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.com.forensic.log
```

When I check the "mysite.com.forensic.log" file there is no timestamp in lines. It doesn't store the timestamps of the each requests. Is there anyway to include a timestamp in the log? Log looks like this.

```
+SOME_MIXED_ID|GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1|Host:HERE.SOME.IP.ADDR|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't store timestamp. You can't change the log format either, according to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html).

You can [correlate with normal logs (which can include timestamp) by using the  `%{forensic-id}n`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html) format string for logging. This will give you the time stamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've changed my normal log format and forensic-id appears.